# Цикл для порядковой регрессии R

Tags: r

Я относительно новичок в *R*, и поэтому мне нужна ваша помощь.

Для анализа огромного массива данных *ай-трекера* я использую порядковую регрессию. В очень сокращенном виде данные выглядят так:

```
sNumber  blockNo running TrialNo    wordTar   wordTar1   Freq Len code code2
1        1       1       5           spouse    violent   5011   6    1     2
1        1       1       5          violent     spouse  17873   7    2     1
1        1       1       5           spouse    aviator   5011   6    1     1
1        1       1       5          aviator       wife    515   7    1     1
1        1       1       5             wife    aviator  87205   4    1     1
1        1       1       5          aviator     spouse    515   7    1     1
1        1       1       9        stability    usually  12642   9    1     3
1        1       1       9          usually   requires  60074   7    3     4
1        1       1       9         requires     client  25949   8    4     1
1        1       1       9           client   requires  16964   6    1     4
2        2       1       5            grimy      cloth    757   5    2     1
2        2       1       5            cloth       eats   8693   5    1     4
2        2       1       5             eats    whitens   3494   4    4     4
2        2       1       5          whitens      woman     18   7    4     1
2        2       1       5            woman    penguin 162541   5    1     1
2        2       1       9              pie   customer   8909   3    1     1
2        2       1       9         customer  sometimes  13399   8    1     3
2        2       1       9        sometimes reimburses  96341   9    3     4
2        2       1       9       reimburses  sometimes     65  10    4     3
2        2       1       9        sometimes   gangster  96341   9    3     1
```

В данной таблице важные столбцы:

- `sNumber` - номер испытуемого,
- `runningTrilaNo` - номер показанного дисплея,
- `wordTar` - слова, на которые смотрел испытуемый в течение предъявления одного дисплея (это также зависимая переменная),
- `Freq` и `Len` - независимые переменные для анализа.

У меня есть код для анализа одного дисплея одного испытуемого:

```
read.delim(file.choose(), header=TRUE) -> eyeData

ss <- subset(eyeData, sNumber == 1 & runningTrialNo == 5) # extract the 5th trial from the 1st participant

ss.s <- ss[!duplicated(ss$wordTar), ] # delete duplicates = refixations

ss.s$lFreq <- log(ss.s$Freq) # change the raw frequencies to log freq

ss.s$rankF <- as.factor(seq(nrow(ss.s))) #  add a new column with sequential numbers as a factor 

m <- clm(rankF~lFreq*Len, data=ss.s, link='probit') #estimate an ordered logistic regression model - fit ordered logit model

summary(m)

(ci <- confint(m)) # get confidence intervals (CI)

exp(coef(m)) # odd ratios (OR)
```

Всего у меня  41 участник исследования, и у каждого по 78 показанных дисплеев. В моем коде я работаю только с одним дисплеем одного испытуемого. Как вы понимаете, нужно много времени, чтобы проанализировать так данные всех участников. Не могли бы вы мне помочь написать петлю (*loop*) для анализа всех 78 дисплеев всех 41 участников и для сохранения нужных мне данных (`summary(m), ci, and coef(m)`) в один файл?

Comment: а что имеется в виду под "сохранением в один файл"? в текстовом виде вывод просто? или все же нужна таблица с регрессионными коэффициентами и их CI? можно пример вывода?

Comment: можно в текстовом виде, чтобы были видны p-values & estimates. таблиц и графиков пока не надо

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, я бы логистическую регрессию задавал иначе

```
glm.fit <- glm(factor(wordTar) ~  Freq + Len, data = ss.s, family = binomial(link = "probit"))
summary(glm.fit)
```

И/или посмотрел бы вот сюда: 
http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/probit.htm

Во-вторых, в data.table логистическая для всех сегментов выглядела бы примерно так:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(ss.s)
ss.s.models <- ss.s[, list(model = list(glm(factor(wordTar) ~  Freq + Len, data = .SD, family = binomial(link = "probit"))), by = list(sNumber, runningTrilaNo)]
ss.s.models.parameters <- ss.s.models[, list(model.ci = confint(model), model.coef = coef(model), model.summary = summary(model), by = list(sNumber, runningTrilaNo)]
```

Так как `confint(model)` и проч. - это листы, то надо либо указывать, какие их элементы нужны, либо потом просто выводить на печать:

```
ss.s.models.parameters[sNumber == 1 & runningTrialNo == 5, model.ci]
```

Вообще, неудобно без примера данных, с которыми можно было бы поработать напрямую, поэтому не уверен, что точно так сработает, может быть, придется кое-где допиливать.

Comment: а ты уверен, что factor(wordTar) правильную последовательность задаст? ей же нужно, как я понял, от 1 до N по порядку уровни, а тут по алфавиту скорее будет (или нет)

Comment: Филипп, спасибо! но мне именно нужна порядковая регрессия - 1 до N для каждой Trial.

Answer (score 2):

Цикл здесь писать не стоит, мне кажется, R все-таки векторный язык. Советую сделать примерно так:

```
eyedata<-unique(eyedata, by=c('sNumber','runningTrialNo','wordTar'))
eyedata[,rankF:=1:.N, by=list(sNumber,runningTrialNo)]
eyedata[,lFreq:=log(Freq+0.001)] #to avoid NAs on zeros

get_res<-function (x) {
  tryCatch({
    m<-clm(factor(rankF)~lFreq*Len, data=x, link='probit')
    ci <- confint(m)
    exp_coef<-exp(coef(m))
    coef_mat<-tail(coef(summary(m)), 3)
    cbind(coef_mat, ci, exp_coef)
  }, error = function(e){
    data.frame()
  })
}
eyedata[,data.frame(get_res(.SD)), by=list(sNumber,runningTrialNo) ]
```

Ну а дальше уже что угодно с этим выводом можно делать.

UPD. Ответ обновлен в соответствии с примером данных из комментариев. Добавлен error-handling.

Comment: полезная функция, спасибо. однако мне показывает в конце Error in qr.default(X, tol = tol, LAPACK = FALSE) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1). эти NAs у меня и при ручном анализе каждой trial встречается... при том, что в данных никаких NAs нет. в общем, мне сначала с этими NAs надо разобраться, а потом твой код запускать

Comment: если ты выкинешь кусок данных с пары испытуемых, я смогу потестить

Comment: в смысле отправить тебе кусок данных моих?

Comment: выложи на файлообменник и сделай ссылку тут, так и другим будет проще проверять их решения

Comment: вот данные 3 испытуемых. первый файл - csv, второй - txt

http://wikisend.com/download/352704/test.csv

http://wikisend.com/download/245132/test.txt

Comment: Я обновил ответ, на примере теперь все работает. У тебя с данными несколько проблем: 1) нули в частотах - сейчас я добавляю к логарифму 0.001, чтобы избежать NA, возможно это не лучший вариант. 2) регрессия на отдельных пробах может не сходиться/давать странные результаты/еще что-то - я сейчас добавил error handling, но по хорошему тебе надо подумать о более оптимальных методах анализа.

Comment: спасибо, я тоже уже сижу и думаю про другие виды анализа.

Answer (score 2):

Все гораздо проще.

1) Делаем из таблицы список:

```
datalist <- split(data, list('sNumber','wordTar'))
```

2) Пишем функцию для построение модели и извлечения нужных данных из нее (коэффициенты и пр.).

```
applyFun <- function(x) {
#### здесь код
#### при построении модели задаем 'data=x`, остальное все как обычно
}
```

3) Используем `lapply()`:

```
results <- lapply(datalist, FUN = applyFUN)
```

Результат можно превратить из списка  в таблицу при помощи

```
do.call(rbind, results)
```

Comment: а чем это проще eyedata[,get_res(.SD), by=list(sNumber,runningTrilaNo) ]?

Comment: Только базовый функционал, никаких дополнительных пакетов и однострочное решение в итоге - получается проще.

Comment: Ну, оно не однострочное =) в data.table можно было бы также сделать, даже оставив в функции весь тот код, который автор написала в вопросе. Но код в вопросе далек от эффективного. Кроме того, рискну предположить, что вариант с data.table будет работать гораздо быстрее. Впрочем, все это, конечно, вопрос вкусов.